# Popular um ComboBox a partir da seleção de outro ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, ado.net

Eu realmente não faço ideia de como fazer isso, porém se isso for realmente possível seria muito útil para mim, tentei de algumas formas mas nenhuma deu certo

Eu tenho um `ComboBox` **`cboBusca`** onde eu seleciono o que eu quero buscar no `DataGridView`

> Ex: LINHAS, FIDELIDADE, CONTRATO e etc

E um outro `ComboBox` **`cboCriterio`** onde eu definiria o que eu quero buscar

> Ex: A+, NOVO CONTRATO, EXPIRADO e etc

Então eu gostaria basicamente após eu escolher um valor no **`cboBusca`** ele populasse o **`cboCriterio`** já que o que eu estou filtrando são meio que valores fixos eu poderia adicionar manualmente o que eu quero que apareça no **`cboCriterio`** após selecionar uma determinada opção no **`cboBusca`**.

Comment: Os itens do `cboCriterio` serão preenchidos por registros do Banco de Dados, correto?

Comment: não eu mesmo iria preencher ele manualmente como eu tinha citado, por exemplo
`IF(cboBusca == FIDELIDADE){
cboCriterio.Items.Add("Fidelizado");
cboCriterio.Items.Add("Não Fidelizado");
cboCriterio.Items.Add("Vencido");`

Comment: porém dessa forma não funciona mas a lógica seria essa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie o evento `SelectedIndexChanged` para o `cboBusca` e teste desta forma:

```
private void cboBusca_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cboCriterio.Items.Clear();

    if (cboBusca.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        cboCriterio.Items.Add("Fidelizado"); 
        cboCriterio.Items.Add("Não Fidelizado"); 
        cboCriterio.Items.Add("Vencido");
    }
    else if(cboBusca.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        cboCriterio.Items.Add("Expirado"); 
        cboCriterio.Items.Add("Não Expirado"); 
        cboCriterio.Items.Add("Teste");
    }
}
```